# A way to infer types based on the return value of the function in react prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, generics, flatlist

So i have this component definition that accepts two generics

```
function AsyncFlatList<ApiResponse, Item>({}: {
  url: string;
  transformResponse: (response: ApiResponse) => Item[];
  keyExtractor: (item: Item) => string;
}) {
  // ignore the implementation
  return <></>;
}
```

I call the component like this

```
type Post = {
    id: number
    title: string
    body: string
    userId: number
}

type PostMapped = {
   id: string
   title: string
   body: string
}

<AsyncFlatList<Post[], PostMapped>
  url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
  transformResponse={(response) => response}
  // The type of post params below is coming from `PostMapped`
  keyExtractor={(post) => post.id}
/>
```

The problem is that I don't want to define `PostMapped` explicitly. I want it to be inferred from the type of the return value on the `transformResponse` prop.

So that i can use the component like this:

```
<AsyncFlatList<Post[]>
  url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
  transformResponse={(response) =>
     response.map((singleResponse) => ({
       id: singleResponse.id.toString(),
       title: singleResponse.title,
       body: singleResponse.body,
     }))
  }
 // post types below will be inferred based on what's return from transformResponse
 // that is why we can use post.id directly without types issue because it is already transformed to string
 // in the transformResponse prop above
  keyExtractor={(post) => post.id}
/>
```

and I don't have to define `PostMapped` anymore since it will be inferred.

Kindly help to achieve that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the minimal changes to your code, here is an example.

```
import React from 'react';

function AsyncFlatList<ApiResponse, Item = unknown>({}: {
  url: string;
  transformResponse: (response: ApiResponse) => Item[];
  keyExtractor: (item: Item) => string;
}) {
  // ignore the implementation
  return <></>;
}
type Post = {
    id: number
    title: string
    body: string
    userId: number
}

const MyList: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <AsyncFlatList
    url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    transformResponse={(response: Post[]) =>
        response.map((singleResponse) => ({
          id: singleResponse.id.toString(),
          title: singleResponse.title,
          body: singleResponse.body,
        }))}
    keyExtractor={(post) => post.id}
    />);
}
```

In fact, the ApiResponse generic argument is not needed in your case (but I don't know if you'll need it later in your implementation).

---

Edit:
After reading your comment I think I better understand what result you want to really achieve: You want to define the contract of AsyncFlatList by passing the generic argument  and inferring from the type of `transformResponse` at the same time.

And It is not possible. You either explicitly pass the type arguments or let type argument inference do the job.

Let's look at a small non-react example:

```
//@ts-ignore
function testing<A,B>(cb1: (a:A)=>B, cb2: (b:B)=>string);
testing((a: Post)=>a, post=>post.body); // pass typecheck
testing<Post>(a=>a, post=>post.body); // fail typecheck, beacuse B is missing
```

```
//@ts-ignore
function testing<A=unknown,B=unknown>(cb1: (a:A)=>B, cb2: (b:B)=>string);
testing((a: Post)=>a, post=>post.body); // pass typecheck
testing<Post>(a=>a, post=>post.body); // fail typecheck, beacuse B is unknown by default
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have tried this before but didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: If i want to remove ApiResopnse altogether. what would be the best type for response params here
`transformResponse: (response: any) => Item[];`

is it okay if i assign `any` to it?

Comment: also with your implementation if i assign the ApiResponse explicitly the keyExtractor params type will break

```tsx
export const MyList: React.FC = () => (
  <AsyncFlatList<Post[]>
    url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    transformResponse={(response) =>
      response.map((singleResponse) => ({
        id: singleResponse.id.toString(),
        title: singleResponse.title,
        body: singleResponse.body,
      }))
    }
    keyExtractor={(post) => post.id}
  />
);
```

Comment: That's why you don't want to explicitly write `AsyncFlatList<Post[]>`, but let the prop types infer themselves. If you look at `react-native` [FlatList typing](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.d.ts), you will find the same approach.

Comment: And for the first question, yes you can assign any to it, since `(response: Post[])=>Item[]` is assignable to `(response: any)=>Item[]`.